# How I can select the coordinate X and Y of R plot from Column Filter (R/Knime)?

Tags: r, knime

So, I have this workflow :

[image]
[image]

I have selected 2 columns(Day and Temperature) from my file using ‘Columns filter’. And I connected to ‘R plot’ that I configurated  but I obtain this :

[image]

The day column is not selected as X axis but (Row ID) and the Y axis is ok.

This is my code in R plot:

```
# Library
library(qcc)
library(readr)
library(Rserve)
Rserve(args = "--vanilla")

# Data column filter from CSV file imported
Test <- kIn

#Background color
qcc.options(bg.margin = "white", bg.figure = "gray95")

#R graph ranges of a continuous process variable
qcc(data = Test,
    type = "R",
    sizes = 5,
    title = "Sample R Chart Title",
    digits = 2,
    plot = TRUE)
```

Comment: Use quick form nodes and use flow variables in R snippets. (With metanodes you can even configure it nicely.)

Answer (score 0):

Here is my try (using KNIME's R, not the community contribution):

```
#install.packages("qcc")
library(qcc)

data <- knime.in
#Change the names to use Day instead of row keys
row.names(data) <- data$Day

#Using the updated data
plot(qcc(data = data,
    type = "R",
    sizes = 5,
    title = "Sample R Chart Title",
    digits = 2,
    plot = TRUE))
```

With results like:

[image: plot using R view]

If you want to select the column for the X axis, just change the `row.names` assignment. (It can also come from `knime.flow.in` in case the column name is coming from a flow variable, but as I understand it is not the case for you.)

Comment: Have you an idea how i can select the Y coordinate if i have several columns ?

Comment: I am not familiar with `qcc`, but maybe passing only the data's proper projection, like `qcc(data = data$Temperature,` might work.

Comment: Unfortunately, if i do `qcc(data = data$Temperature,` there are  problem with limits control UCL and LCL which are on the same line and same value.